# array[index] returns undefined while array itself shows each index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to get some individual chart (graph) data for my lazily loaded items. For this, first I get the items (10 for each lazy load) and then I combine the names of these items and send it (the combined names string) to another API method and get the chart data for those 10 items. Everything seems to work fine until I get to put my Chart component (which is an apexcharts component) into the page. When I try to do so, it always complain about the series tag (attribute) is undefined and therefore, it can't get the [0] index of undefined.

well, to make this work, I first tried to see if everything comes right and are assigned accordingly by placing the console.log entries in the code. And after I see that everything is as it should be, I placed the Chart component code, but no matter what I do, it always says the series attribute is undefined. Basically everything I try to do is in the finally block of the first `Promise.all()`.

[image: here is the image for the console.log outputs]

For those [who can't see the image the link] (https://pasteboard.co/IAf7wNbW.png)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.trendSeries = [];
}


 loadMatters() {

        let self = this;
        Promise.all([ this.getPopularMatters(), this.getResourceStatistics(), this.getPopularSeries()]).then(function (results) {
            let items = (self.state.matters === null ? [] : self.state.matters);
            let pageIndex = self.state.pageIndex;

      items = items.concat(results[0]);
          pageIndex++;

          self.setState({
              matters: items, statisticsByResources: results[1],
          });
      }).finally(function () {

          /// Prepare the names joined by comma to get individual chart data
          let namesArray = [];
          self.state.matters.map((item, index) => {
              namesArray.push(item.name);
          });
          const names = namesArray.join();
          let seriesArray = [];
          let items = self.state.matters;

          /// GET INDIVIDUAL CHART DATA
          Promise.all([self.getIndividualChartsForMatters(names)]).then(function (res) {
              res[0].map((item, index) => {
                  items[index]["series"] = item.series; //put the series data into series property of each item.
                  seriesArray.push(item.series);

              });
          }).finally(function () {

              console.log("seriesArray :", seriesArray);
              console.log("seriesArray INDEX:", seriesArray[0]);

              console.log("results 2 series : ", self.state.chartSeries);
              console.log("R2 type : ", typeof (self.state.chartSeries));
              console.log("index r2 : ", self.state.chartSeries[0]);


              self.trendSeries = seriesArray;
              self.setState({ individualChartSeries: seriesArray });


              console.log("series STATE : ", self.state.individualChartSeries);
              console.log("series STATE INDEX : ", self.state.individualChartSeries[0]);


              console.log("trendSeries : ", self.trendSeries);
              console.log("trendSeries INDEX : ", self.trendSeries[0]);

          });

    });
    }




 render() {


    var items = [];
    this.state.matters &&
      this.state.matters.map((item, index) => (
        items.push(
          <div key={index} className="bg-color-mid-blue border-rad-8px mb-2_0em">
            <div >
              <div className="font-2_9em font-regular text-center line-height-1_1em pr-0_5em color-dark-gray">{item.order}</div>
              <div>
                <span className="d-block font-1_3em mbt-0_25em font-medium white-space-nowrap">{item.name}</span>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        { /// INDIVIDUAL TREND CHART WILL BE HERE
                        }















                    </div>
</div>
</div>);

return(
 <InfiniteScroll

                      loadMore={this.loadMatters}
                      hasMore={this.state.hasMore && !this.state.isLoading}
                      loader={<div className="w-100per text-center pt-2_0em pb-2_0em" key={0}>Loading...</div>}>
                      {items.length > 0 ?
                        items
                        :
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-xl-12 mb-2_0em">
                            <div className="bg-color-mid-blue p-2_0em border-rad-8px mb-2_0em color-mid-gray">
                              No trends to show here...
                        </div></div></div>}
                    </InfiniteScroll>);



}


 PPP
                        <Chart
                            options={this.state.chartOptions}
                            series={this.trendSeries[index]}
                            type="line"
                            height="150px"
                        />


                        SSS
                        <Chart
                            options={this.state.chartOptions}
                            series={this.state.individualChartSeries[index]}
                            type="line"
                            height="150px"
                        />

                        III
                        <Chart
                            options={this.state.chartOptions}
                            series={item.series}
                            type="line"
                            height="150px"
                        />





now when I put any of the above Chart components in the //INDIVIDUAL CHART WILL BE HERE part, I get an error saying that either 'TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined' or 'Cannot read the property 'length' of undefined'. Which ultimately denotes that series attribute of the Chart component is undefined. But as the console.log logs clearly show, the series data (in all formats -trendSeries attribute (field), state variable, or injected into items array- )is correctly obtained.

What am I missing or doing wrong?
```

Comment: Try to reduce your example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I reduced some, but this is, in my opinion, already the smallest part of the code

Comment: Get an example of your problem in codesandbox.io. I guarantee that if you do that, we will find a solution.